# How to center imagine but not caption and cite?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, floats, text-manipulation, german

For my paper I need to add the source for the images I use. to achive that I have my formating like this

```
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/ci-cd-flow-desktop_edited_0.png}
\end{center}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont Abbildung 2: CI/CD \\ Quelle: Sourceurl
```

The issue with that is that I can't generate table of contents for my images, so I tried

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Images/DevOps infinity wheel_SIMPLE.png}
\caption {DevOps Schleife}
\url{Quelle: https://medium.com/taptuit/the-eight-phases-of-a-devops-pipeline-fda53ec9bba}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

I need to change the fontsize of my caption and my url, I also need them to be left and not centered. I've tried a few solutions I found online but nothing really helped. does anyone have an idea how I can have them left and not centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Note that the caption actually uses the entire width and is totally unaffected by \centering etc.  One can achieve the same affect using `\parbox{\linewidth}{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package helps. Try this for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,url,lipsum}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,font=small}
\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{DevOps Schleife\\
         Quelle: \protect\url{https://medium.com/taptuit}}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]